# JDBC read-only performance comparision between ResultSet types

Tags: sql, performance, jdbc, cursor, resultset

When executing SELECT queries on an MS SQL Server 2000 DB, is there any performance difference between using ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE and ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY?

Assuming ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY (aka "Firehose cursor") is the fastest you'll get :)

Comment: Here's a table that compares the alternatives: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/resultSets.html